# php-custom privacy settings with Facebook SDK feed post not working

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am trying to post a simple message on my wall by using the Facebook PHP SDK but I get some troubles when I try to set up custom privacy rules, here is my code:

```
try {

                    $response = (new FacebookRequest(
                      $session, 'POST', '/me/feed', array(
                        'message' => @$_GET['message'],
                        'privacy' => json_encode(array(
                                        'friends' => 'SOME_FRIENDS',
                                        'value' => 'CUSTOM',
                                        'allow' => implode(',', $friends)
                                    ))
                      )
                    ))->execute()->getGraphObject();

                    echo "Posted with id: " . $response->getProperty('id');

                  } catch(FacebookRequestException $e) {

                    echo "Exception occured, code: " . $e->getCode();
                    echo " with message: " . $e->getMessage();

                  }
```

And i get the fallowing error:
Exception occured, code: 100 with message: (#100) 'friends' value was not recognized

Someone could help me ?

**EDIT** The problem is that i do not have the real ID of the the friends, but i do not know how to get it when they do not use my application, any idea ?

Comment: If you look at the documentation. The values for privacy is different between read and publish. For publish privacy only have the keys: value, deny, allow. Not friends.

Answer (score 0):

If you see the [Publish documentation for Feed](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/feed), the privacy settings you are using are invalid. As you can no longer get IDs of friends (unless they use the application), so you cannot restrict posts to a select number of friends who's IDs you do not know.

Comment: I have fond an other way to the a custom privacy settings in order to pick friends who can see even if they do not use application :)

Comment: Well it's not really "good" but it fix problem:
Just tag friends and pick CUSTOM -> SOME_FRIENDS as privacy to post :)